# Different option menus in ViewPager need to be resized

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` in it. The `ViewPager` has 3 `Fragments` in it.

The `Activity` has an **options menu** (with items that are common to all fragments) and the `Fragments` each add items (that are important to that fragment only) to that options menu by inflating a new menu.

One of the `Fragments` has a menu item that has a long title - so, the menu is wide enough to accommodate it.

The other `Fragments`'s items have shorter titles, **but the menu is still really wide** (as if to accommodate that long title which is not there anymore), and that leaves an empty space to the right of the menu.

How can I force the menu to, say, 'wrap_content' the items that are there? I've tried calling activity.invalidateOptionsMenu everytime the fragments are shown, but that didn't change anything. I feel that there's a very simple solution to this that a beginner  like myself just can't see. Call invalidateOptionsMenu somewhere else, maybe?

('calendar settings' is long)[image]

(empty space to the right) [image]

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot depicting the issue?

Comment: @dazza5000, screenshots included!